# Get the first children of a ng-component through @ContentChildren

Tags: angular

I try to get the first children of a component through @ContentChildren

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ing-resizable-view',
  templateUrl: './resizable-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./resizable-view.component.scss']
})
export class ResizableViewComponent implements AfterContentInit{
  constructor() { }
  @ContentChildren(Object) private rootChildren: QueryList<any>;
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log(this.rootChildren.first);
  }
}
```

The component html

```
<ng-content>
</ng-content>
```

This is the HTML that try to use the component

```
<ing-resizable-view class="mat-elevation-z8 panel" cdkDropListGroup>
    <ing-var-tree class="resize" (selectorEvents)="selectedVars=$event" [handlers]="selectedVars"></ing-var-tree>
    <ing-var-list (selectorEvents)="selectedVars=$event" [vars]="selectedVars"></ing-var-list>
</ing-resizable-view>
```

Comment: you need indicate in ContentChildren the type e.g. `IngVarTreeComponent` or a template reference variable

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo  but I plan to use component in several part of my app so I want to reference  the first element whatever it type is . Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return all children component in a generic way without specifying any component selector into `@ContentChildren`.

Solution I can recommend you, is to create a specific dumb directive, for instance,  `ing-main` or `ing-resizable`, which will be applied to one of child components (or all depending on your need).

In this case, you will be able to query one or all components with this directive.

Of course, this will request to add each time the directive to one of child component, but it could be also more powerful and evolutive, if for any reason, the first child doesn't make always sense.

The `ing-main` directive :

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[ing-main]'
})
export class IngMainDirective {
}
```

Your current template code :

```
<ing-resizable-view class="mat-elevation-z8 panel" cdkDropListGroup>
    <ing-var-tree ing-main ...></ing-var-tree>
    <ing-var-list ...></ing-var-list>
</ing-resizable-view>
```

So `ing-resizable-view` component is able to query all child components with this directive :

```
@ContentChildren(IngMainDirective) private children: QueryList<IngMainDirective>;
```